# Unexpected regular expression behavior with /null/g.test('null null')

Tags: javascript, regex, null

```
var re = /null/g;

re.test('null null');
//> true

re.test('null null');
//> true

re.test('null null');
//> false
```

WHAT!?!?

I tried testing in Chrome, Firefox, Safari.
Used regex with RegExp constructor, but to no avail.

Why is this happening?

[JS Bin with additional demo](http://jsbin.com/xovilay/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global regular expressions (those using the `g` flag) are special. If you call them on the same string multiple times, they search for successive matches. Since your test string contains exactly two matches for `null`, the third call to `RegExp#test` returns `false` (a third match in a row cannot be found).

To fix this problem, you can abandon the `g` flag like so:

```js
var re = /null/

console.log(re.test('null null')) //=> true
console.log(re.test('null null')) //=> true
console.log(re.test('null null')) //=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna think about this some more to figure out why this is happening.  But you should remove the "g" from your regex.  It is unnecessary and will fix the problem.

Comment: Hmm, gyre beat be to the punch and with a more informative answer too.